# When debugging fluent style code, how to find which chained method fails?

Tags: java, debugging, stream, fluent, method-chaining

In normal programming style, logics are organized into statements, each takes one line. e.g.

```
statement A;
statement B;
statement C;
...
```

When a bug occurs, the compiler tells me the line number of failing statement. I can easily debug with this narrowed-down scope.

However, now that fluent style code is used (e.g. in Java Stream APIs), long blocks of logic are written in one statement in the form of chained method. For example:

```
 methodA()
  .methodB()
  .methodC()
  .methodD()
  ....
```

When failure happens, what is a good way to narrow down to which chained method fails? My concern is that compiler's debug hint only has a line number, but the entire chained block is contained in this one line statement, which is not very helpful for debugging.

Comment: The stack trace also shows method names, so it would uniquely identify which method A, B, C or D the exception occurred in.  So as long as you don’t call the same method more than once, it shouldn’t be a problem even if the calls were all on one physical line, instead of individual lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code the chained methods on different lines.

When chained methods are coded on different lines, the stacktrace contains the line number of the method call that failed.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    MyClass okMethod() {
        return this;
    }

    MyClass explodingMethod() {
        throw new RuntimeException();  // line 10
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass()
                .okMethod()
                .explodingMethod() // line 16
                .okMethod();
    }
}
```

Executing this causes an exception with this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at MyClass.explodingMethod(MyClass.java:10)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:16) // this is the call that exploded
```

Note that the line number within the stacktrace shows which actual method invocation exploded.